# sqlite get rownumber in result with group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite and i want to show the row number in the result of query, after search i find this below line as solution:

`SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl AS tbl_row WHERE tbl_row.id <= tbl.id) AS rowNum, id, name, code FROM tbl`

this is work perfectly without any problem but when i'm trying to use `GROUB BY code` on above line i get the **wrong** number as rowNum

ok, how can i get the rowNumber in sqlite when i use GROUP BY in query SELECT ?

thanks

Comment: If there are multiple rowNum values for a given code, which rowNum value do you want to be listed? The maximum / minimum? Because when you GROUP BY code, there will be only one record for each value of code.

Comment: When there are multiple rows in a group, from which one should the `id` and `name` values come?